# crystal report formula for ordering the Days of week

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I want to make the crystal report formula to show the "Week days" in its correct order e.g. Monday, Tuesday etc. Please if any one knows it, suggest me. I will be very thankful. Thanks in advance
[image]

Comment: I tried weekdayname(DayofWeek()) but it is showing "Not enough arguments have been given to this function. Please help

Comment: well what are the other arguments that it expects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WeekdayName(DayOfWeek()). You just need to pass it the report date field.

For example like this:

```
WeekdayName(DayOfWeek({MyTable.MyDateColumn}))
```

If you just need a calculated field for sorting the result, you might just use

```
DayOfWeek({MyTable.MyDateColumn})
```

If you consider Monday the first day of week you can use the second, optional parameter

```
DayOfWeek({MyTable.MyDateColumn}, crMonday)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. it is helpful. I also found a way to do the same in the specified order group name. Thanks again